# Why does the statement 5 * 1.015 not return 5.075?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

It returns

```
5.074999999999999
```

Why is that?

And what other numbers will give a similar demonstration of this?

Comment: For more on this topic see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: Why vote down on a (self) closed question?

Comment: `1.015` is an infinite fraction in binary, i.e. it cannot be represented in the finite precision. The same holds true for `5 * 1.015`.

Comment: @EranMedan my guess is that people think that even if you turn yourself to the police, the crime remains

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essential reading on floating point arithmetic.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

In a nutshell:

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
>   requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
>   many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
>   be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits,
>   most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that
>   cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the
>   result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order
>   to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
>   characteristic feature of floating-point computation.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the classic example is:

```
0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004
```

[IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) double-precision floating-point numbers (which is what [JavaScript uses](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)) are *very very good*, but they're not perfect. They offer a fast way of doing mostly-correct, but not perfect, computation on floating-point numbers. All number systems have such compromises (try to *accurately* represent `1 / 3` — or PI, for that matter — in a limited number of decimal digits, for instance).

Answer (score 4):

It’s normal – There’s a thing called precision while working with floating point numbers. It’s present in most of the modern languages. See here: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html for more information.

In this line of thought – you cannot compare floating point numbers without using EPS (epsilon value). If you need more information – feel free to contact me again.